# How to get Lat,Lang of already created polygon using google map api in php

Tags: php, google-maps

I am developing an application where I am storing polygon which is created using Google Map API. I have created a link to view saved zone on map. When I click on "**view zone**" link it show me that polygon on map. Now I edit that zone, so that coordinates are changed. Now i want to get that new coordinates and want to save. How can I get that coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From google developer doc

> Inspect a polygon
>
> A polygon specifies its series of coordinates as an array of arrays,
>   where each array is of type MVCArray. Each "leaf" array is an array of
>   LatLng coordinates specifying a single path. To retrieve these
>   coordinates, call the Polygon object's getPaths() method. Since the
>   array is an MVCArray you will need to manipulate and inspect it using
>   the following operations:
>
> - getAt() returns the LatLng at a given zero-based index value.
> - insertAt() inserts a passed LatLng at a given zero-based index value. Note that any existing coordinates at that index value are
>     moved forward.
> - removeAt() removes a LatLng at a given zero-based index value.

this is the link for doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes

you can add a listner to you polygon

```
yourPolygon.addListener('click', showArrays);
```

and with the related a shoArrays function

```
/** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
function showArrays(event) {
  var points= this.getPath();


  for (var i =0; i <points.getLength(); i++) {
    var xy = points.getAt(i);
    alert('Lat ' + xy.lat + ' Lng ' + xy.lng );
 }
}
```

accessing to the coords

Comment: Not Work for me :( .

I want all coordinate after edit zone when I click on "Update zone" Button. How can I get this?

Comment: then show your code, you tell the code proposed don't work.. but i can't evalute if have other problem without see your code..

Comment: There is some mistake from my side, so this is not working. Sorry.

Now I have change my code and its working. Thanks....

Comment: How can I get Final Coordinate after I drag polygon from 1 place to other place. Means I will drag a polygon from 1 place and put it to other place then how can I got that final coordinates of polygon?

Answer (score 0):

To get Coordinate after edit you have to add listener where you have created polygon otherwise it will not work properly.